# General name for these type of images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

What is the general name for these images with lots of icons and small items sketched (or outlined), they are quite popular these days. Evernote and Whatsapp for example uses them:

http://pocketyourshop.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/evernote.png

http://cdn9.staztic.com/app/a/2063/2063485/whatsapp-wallpaper-pack-4-724187-0-s-307x512.jpg

I'm looking for a tutorial or free images for my app's splash screen, so I need to know how to google them. Though I'm moderately good with Photoshop I don't have much hand drawing skills. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd call it a collage wallpaper pattern. The images the collage is made of couldbe called line-drawing icons or pictograms (or, iconographic line drawings).

- Collage - image made of a mix of images
- Wallpaper - background image intended to be aesthetic but unintrusive
- Pattern - a tile that repeats.

For tutorials, I'd look for two separate types - tutorials on line-drawing icons (or "sketched", or "hand drawn" etc), and tutorials on collage patterns, then combine the two remembering that a wallpaper should never take attention away from the foreground.