# Structured pattern, random elements in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, tools, symbols

I'm trying to make a subtle background out of a collection of symbols, arranged in randomly order in multiple roughly structured rows.

A bit like:
[image: G+ Background]

The Symbol Sprayer Tool is close to what I need, but it distributes only a single symbol in a circular area rather than along a line.

How can I create something like this?

Comment: Its probably easier to place the objects manually to make sure the spacing is as you want it.

Comment: There's a helluva lot of space to fill, and a fair number of symbols to use... hence I'm looking for automated methods.

Comment: Are the symbols the same size or do they vary? Same size is *kind of* easy. Or at least easier. Varying sizes can only be done manually. Illustrator has no "auto-fit" functions. Your sample is a repeating pattern :)

Comment: More or less the same size. So you're suggesting creating a pattern manually and just repeating it? Bleurgh, that sounds distinctly like effort :P I think there might be call to build a little plugin for this...

Comment: Slightly relevant: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/18829/8845

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I couldn't find a mechanism to automatically distribute and repeat a pattern, but **[this article](http://mrare.ca/blog/how-to-make-a-repeatable-pattern-in-illustrator) on *The Noun Project's* blog** did give a really good runthrough of how to do it; manually, but reliably and relatively easily.

**Summary of article**

> [image]
>   The most important thing to note, is that each shape on the edge of
>   our square needs to have a duplicate icon exactly in the same position
>   on the other side. This is super easy to do **since our pattern is
>   300x300px, as all we need to do is open the transform window (Window >
>   Transform), and type in +300 after the value in the X field.** Adding
>   300 pixels will move our icon over to the right, while subtracting 300
>   pixels will move it to the left. The same can be said for the Y axis,
>   only adding pixels will move the object down, and subtracting pixels
>   will move it up.
>   [image]
>   ...
>
> [image]
>
> With the selection tool, highlight all the elements of the pattern
>   (including the square unfilled shape) and drag it into your swatches
>   panel (Window > Swatches). In the dialogue window that pops up, select
>   ‘Pattern brush”.
>   [image]

Comment: If you can summarise the key points of that article (use a grid, setting up the pattern, etc) that'd make a really good, useful answer that'll still be useful if that link goes down.

Comment: @user568458 - done!

Comment: And the link is now down, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

AstuteGraphic's [ColliderScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/) Plugin might be able to help you. If you see on their page, the offset spacing function allows you to place irregular objects a certain distance from each other.

If you combine that with the [seamless pattern tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/define-pattern.html) you should be able to achieve the effect you describe